# Apps to compile code on iPad

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, developer-program

Is there an app, or many, to compile code in different languages such as python, C, Java, etc?

I bought Buffer Editor, mostly for Web development, but I also know some other languages, and we can only edit the code on that app.

Comment: There are tons of IDE on iOS. What is the need to “compile” - is that on device or are you ok with CI/CD/interpreted toolchains?

Comment: This is likely too broad a question. It I’m refraining from voting to close to give you some time to edit this - the [meta] has guidance on asking for software recommendations where you list specific features and show some research if possible

Comment: It's hard to tell what you need. Apple's Swift Playrgounds will run Swift code on an iPad. [Pythonista](https://omz-software.com/pythonista/) will run Python code. I can't tell if either of those is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You will need Xcode on a Mac to build native code for an iPad. For Python you can use Pythonista which I find very useful for smaller Python programs on an iPad.

https://omz-software.com/pythonista/